# How to get the available X cursor sizes?

Tags: x11, xcursor

Suppose you have several X cursors on your system such as `golden-xcursors` or `silver-xcursors`. I already know it's possible to specify which cursor size you prefer by editing `~/.Xresources`. For example:

```
Xcursor.theme: Gold
Xcursor.size: 16
```

But how can I get the list of available X cursor sizes to choose from (for example: 32, 48 or 64)? Is there a command for that?

Comment: A shell command is likely the only portable solution.  There are a few platform-specific things such  as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [xcursor-viewer](https://github.com/drizt/xcursor-viewer) to look inside the cursor file and see what sizes are available.

It lacks documentation. To build and run it I had to do this:

1. Download the source code, for example by cloning the git repository.
2. In its directory, run `cmake .`. I (on Ubuntu) got an error that I was missing Qt5, and I solved this by installing the `qt5-default` package and then trying again.
3. Run `make`
4. Run `./xcursor-viewer <path-to-cursor>`

[image: Screenshot of xcursor-viewer in action, showing the Fedora Core 6 "Bluecurve" cursors, with focus on the "left_ptr" cursor. It shows three available sizes.]

Comment: this is the most amazing answer ive found ever. thank you so much for step by step instruction!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the sizes from the output of `xdd -c12 -g4 -e <cursor> | head`. E.g. for DMZ-White from dmz-cursor-theme on Ubuntu 22.04 this looks like

```shellsession
$ xxd -c12 -g4 -e /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/X_cursor | head
00000000: 72756358 00000010 00010000  Xcur........
0000000c: 00000003 fffd0002 00000018  ............
00000018: 00000034 fffd0002 00000020  4....... ...
00000024: 00000958 fffd0002 00000030  X.......0...
00000030: 0000197c 00000024 fffd0002  |...$.......
0000003c: 00000018 00000001 00000018  ............
00000048: 00000018 0000000b 0000000b  ............
00000054: 00000032 00000000 00000000  2...........
00000060: 00000000 00000000 00000000  ............
0000006c: 00000000 00000000 00000000  ............
```

The following parts of the output are relevant:

00000000: 72756358 00000010 00010000  **Xcur**........ 
0000000c: **00000003** *fffd0002* **00000018**  ............ 
00000018: 00000034 *fffd0002* **00000020**  4....... ... 
00000024: 00000958 *fffd0002* **00000030**  X.......0...

- The bold marked `Xcur` at the top right ensures this is a Xcursor file
- The bold marked `00000003` at the top left are the number of relevant following lines (in hex)
- The italic marked `fffd0002` ensures the line corresponds to a cursor size.
  If it shows `fffd0001` instead, ignore the line!
- The bold marked `00000018`, `00000020` and `00000030` are the cursor sizes in hex

In this case, the Xcursor file contains three cursors in the sizes 24, 32 and 48 (in decimal).